# I don't understand the PlatformID enum

Tags: c#, macos, unix

Why does the [PlatformID Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a8hyw88.aspx) contain Unix and MacOSX if .NET does not support these platforms?

Comment: Instead of posting a huge screenshot of your entire development environment, please link to the enum you're actually talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .NET framework is a specification, as are the various .NET languages. While Microsoft only provides implementations of these specifications for Windows, there are other teams (Mono being the chief and most notable example) who provide alternate implementations for Linux, MacOS, and Windows.

Comment: Plus Microsoft has published a cross-platform CLR implementation, Rotor.

Answer (score 0):

PlatformID is just an Enumeration The real value you get is from [OperatingSystem.Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operatingsystem.platform.aspx) And that is Implementation Dependent.